# Extracting data from text file using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that I am trying to extract data from using regular expressions, here is a sample of the text file :

```
 Card number: 9999*********2789, SEQ: 195
Current session ID: 175
 21/01/2021 09:53:41 : Session terminated
```

Here is the regular expression I am using to get most of the data i want :

```
regex = r"number:\s(\d+\*+\d+).*?ID:\s*(\d*).*?ATM:\s(\w+).*?STAN:\s(\d+).*?Total cash dispensed:\s*([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*).*?completed[\r\n]+(.*?)\s:"
```

The output is like this:

In the fourth column '4000 MGA' i want to have it separated into two columns with '4000' and 'MGA', I tried using the following expression but I get no results :

```
regex = r"number:\s(\d+\*+\d+).*?ID:\s*(\d*).*?ATM:\s(\w+).*?STAN:\s(\d+).*?cass 1:\s*\d*([a-zA-Z ]*).?Total cash dispensed:\s*([0-9 ]*).*?completed[\r\n]+(.*?)\s:"
```

Comment: Try this: `r"number:\s(\d+\*+\d+).*?ID:\s*(\d*).*?ATM:\s(\w+).*?STAN:\s(\d+).*?Total cash dispensed:\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*?completed[\r\n]+(.*?)\s:"`

Comment: Hey @anubhava that did the trick thank you so much, you are a life saver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just break that one capture group into 2 and separate them out with whitespaces:

```
regex = r"number:\s(\d+\*+\d+).*?ID:\s*(\d*).*?ATM:\s(\w+).*?STAN:\s(\d+).*?Total cash dispensed:\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*?completed[\r\n]+(.*?)\s:"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wrD33T/1)